# Using ConfigurableActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider in Spring.Net

Tags: spring.net, provider, activedirectorymembership, configurable

I want to use `ConfigurableActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` in my code. I have my current settings as

```
<add name="XXXXMembershipProvider" 
     type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershi pProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"       
     connectionStringName="XXXXConnectionString"     
     connectionUsername="user"
     connectionPassword="password"
     connectionProtection="Secure" />
```

I have changed this to

```
<add connectionStringName="" 
     name="XXXXDomainADMembershipProvider" 
     type="Spring.Web.Providers.MembershipProviderAdapter, Spring.Web" />
```

and added in to my spring config file as

```
<object id="XXXXDomainADMembershipProvider" 
        type="Spring.Web.Providers.ConfigurableActiveDirec toryMembershipProvider">
    <property name="connectionStringName" value="XXXXDomainConnectionString" />
    <property name="connectionUsername" value="user" />
    <property name="connectionPassword" value="password" /> 
</object>
```

But I am getting the following error

**Error creating context 'spring.root': Could not load type from string value 'Spring.Web.Providers.ConfigurableActiveDirectoryM embershipProvider'.**

I checked the `Spring.WebQuickStart` source code and the class `Spring.Web.Providers.ConfigurableActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` has been commented out.

Is that the reason I am getting the above error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you are correct. The error you are getting is exactly the error Spring returns when you are trying to configure an object using a type that can not be loaded. For instance if the class does not exist at all, which appears to be the case here.

You can double check if the `ConfigurableActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` class exists by using the object browser to explore the `Spring.Web.Providers` namespace in the `Spring.Web` assembly you are using in your project.

You are right that the [class is commented out](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-net/trunk/src/Spring/Spring.Web/Web/Providers/ConfigurableActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.cs?hb=true) in the current state of the trunk code. It has a small TBD note, so I think they are not sure if they want to implement this. But it could be that it wasn't commented out in the version of `Spring.Web` you are using, so you should still check it using the object explorer.

Strangely enough, the `ConfigurableActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`[is mentioned in the documentation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web.html#web-di) - you might want to post this on the [Spring.Net forum](http://forum.springframework.net/) they're likely to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Using Object Browser I couldnt find ConfigurableActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider  class in the Spring.Web assembly. I have posted my question in Spring.Net forum as well. I tried to uncomment the ConfigurableActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider class and it works. But still waiting for the reply from Spring.net forum.

Comment: [post on spring.net forum](http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?t=5398)